# Can't drag move the custom messagebox（custom widow） by MouseLeftButtonDown

Tags: c#, wpf, command, custom-controls, behavior

Now, I'm creating a MessageBox(a **Custom Control**, not a User Control) inherits from Window, and provide a style in a ResourceDictionary for it.

Like this :
[image]

I hope I can drag move the messagebox by MouseLeftButtonDown and move the `Blue TitleBar`, but it don't work with my method .

This is my implementation:

.cs:

```
namespace Wpf.Controls
{
    ...
    public MessageBoxModule()
    {
        ...
        SetupDragMoveCommand();
        ...
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DragMoveCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DragMoveCommand",
            typeof(RoutedCommand),
            typeof(MessageBoxModule));

    public RoutedCommand DragMoveCommand
    {
        get { return (RoutedCommand)GetValue(DragMoveCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DragMoveCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public void DragMoveCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DragMove();
    }

    private void SetupDragMoveCommand()
    {
        DragMoveCommand = new RoutedCommand(
            "DragMoveCommand",
            typeof(MessageBoxModule));

        CommandBindings.Add(
            new CommandBinding(DragMoveCommand, DragMoveCommandExecuted));
    }
    ...
}
```

.xmal:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MessageBoxModule}">
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MessageBoxModule}">
                    <!--RootLayoutPanel-->
                    <DockPanel x:Name="RootLayoutPanel">
                        <Grid x:Name="TopSiderLayout">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="DragRectangle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="#FF499A82" >
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{TemplateBinding DragMoveCommand}"/
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Rectangle>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I still don't know why using InvokeCommandAction to TemplateBinding Command which is a Dependency Properties defined in MessageBoxModule don't work.

But I find another method that using **TemplatePart** like this:

.cs:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    Rectangle rect = GetTemplateChild("PART_TitleRectangle") as Rectangle;
    if (rect != null)
    {
        rect.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) => { DragMove(); };
    }
}
```

.xaml:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="PART_TitleRectangle" ... />
```